# JAVA_HOME is not working in maven

Tags: maven, terminal, java-home

java is installed at this path

```sh
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

mvn -version is giving this error

```sh
$ mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I have tried some of the solutions that were available online, but those don't work for me. Some of those solutions suggested adding

```sh
$export JAVA_HOME = /usr/libexec/java_home
```

or

```sh
$export JAVA_HOME = $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

to below files

```sh
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
```

---

Also when I try to execute one shell command, it shows me error like

```sh
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
 CARBON cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute manually `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java --version`? On Mac i would suggest to use ` /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/‌​Home/bin/java --version` ?

Comment: Somewhat late now, but I suspect that most of the OPs problem would have been caused either by their using spaces around the = when setting the environment value or failing to source the bashrc file after editing.

Comment: If you use jEnv, you can try `jenv enable-plugin maven`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

After struggling for almost a day, I found out that maven is *not* reading the `$JAVA_HOME` from either of

```sh
 ~/.bashrc
 ~/.bash_profile
 ~/.profile
```

but it reads `$JAVA_HOME` from  `~/.mavenrc`

So finally, when I added

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home
```

in `~/.mavenrc`  then got output

```sh
mvn -v
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_141, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Thank you. The hint that maven is looking for $JAVA_HOME in the ~/.mavenrc instead of the shell environment variables is correct.

Comment: Tank you so much!! I've been fiddling with this problem for almost two days. :)

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, there is something that needs fixing on the machine. Maven uses JAVA_HOME env as long as it is exported to the environment.

Comment: I installed maven from homebrew and I don't see .mavenrc in home directory. I created the file and it started working!.

Answer (score 23):

To fixed it, update the JAVA_HOME like following :

```
$ vim .bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

$ source .bash_profile
```

Run Maven again :

```
$ mvn -version
```

Comment: I have followed all the steps you have said, but I am still getting the same issue. java home path is updated as below
 $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Its saying JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE. Make sure you have JDK in place not JRE.

Answer (score 12):

maven reads JAVA_HOME from ~/.mavenrc. Add path for JAVA_HOME to ~./mavenrc and source it.

$ vim ~/.mavenrc

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

$ source .mavenrc

Comment: It really helped.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 
I faced a similar problem. I configured `$JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment` 
like `JAVA_HOME=PATH_TO_JDK` for example `JAVA_HOME=/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144`

Careful with

- White space after path declaration `JAVA_HOME=/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144[[_NO_WHITE_SPACE_AFTER_DECLARATION]]`
- Don't put any quotes, e.g. `JAVA_HOME="/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144"`
- Don't put `/bin`, e.g. `JAVA_HOME=/home/max/jdk1.8.0_144/bin` <- This is wrong

Comment: for LinuxMint (19.3) adding $JAVA_HOME to /etc/environment did not produce any effects. I had to (a) create `~/.mavenrc` file (b) add the variable definition to it as `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/` (c) and do `source ~/.mavenrc` .

Answer (score 1):

Please check once there should be no ';' in JAVA_HOME value, if there is semicolon then it would show above error.

Answer (score 0):

I had

> JAVA_HOME

set but did not `export` it and maven was not picking up the correct `JAVA_HOME`.

Once I exported `JAVA_HOME` then it got resolved. Do not forget to export `JAVA_HOME` so that the variable is available to child processes (UNIX* like OS)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```